# How is output power related to input power?

Tags: voltage, watts

Please Note: I stumbled upon this forum after considerable googling but was not able to understand the answers I found. Your simplest terms and explanations are appreciated.

I plan to bring a piece of medical equipment to a location where electricity is limited (think - one or two solar panels and a battery).

The medical equipment has four different models. The main differences being the max output power. For simplicity: A) 400W B) 300W C)200W D) 150W.

How is the max output related to the amount of power used?

If electricity is limited, is it best to choose the lowest wattage?

Thanks,
K

Updated with Links:
Catalogue: http://www.buykorea.org/images/namo/files/000024/20170602151711993_J91SJLC8.pdf

Website:
150 & 200 http://www.daiwha.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=sub1_3_eng&wr_id=1
300 & 400 http://www.daiwha.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=sub1_3_eng&wr_id=2

Comment: Only the documentation of the device can tell, it may scale (linearliy or not) or it may throw away additional power as heat, who knows.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! By documentation are you referring to a specific piece of information? Such as the main frequency, power source, etc?

Comment: usually devices come with a bit of paperwork that states various technical details...

Comment: It is difficult to give you a reliable answer. If the piece of medical equipment has a manufacturer and model name or number, we might have a better chance of giving you a good answer. HOWEVER, it is very, very likely that setting the device to its lowest output power setting will directly translate to using less solar/battery power.

Comment: If I were attempting this, I'd search for the documentation by model number (e.g. google Philips 12345 "Patient Monitor" Installation Manual) and edit the question to link to the datasheet. At least the boilerplate on the back of the appliance should list the max input power requirements. If the medical appliance input requires AC and I only have solar and batteries (DC), then I would also need to bring an *Inverter* to make AC. How long it can run relates to the appliance's input power rating, the battery Amp×Hours capacity, and the inverter's efficiency. Unanswerable without these details.

Comment: It is impossible to tell for sure given the lack of information, but I would think that an instrument that outputs 150 watts will require an input of around 300 watts (assuming 50% efficiency).  One or two solar panels and a battery will not suffice to power such an instrument (unless the panels are very large).

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments. @MarkU I have edited the above with the information I have been able to find from the website and their sales catalogue. I could not find a manual.

Comment: Can you find information on what the device's power supply outputs, and whether its built-into the device or external to it?

Comment: @KayB - As explained in the off-topic box above, questions about equipment bought as manufactured items, are not a good fit here. The best source of information about equipment from manufacturer X **is** manufacturer X (or their agent). Without going into details, I found the correct web page for the 150W & 200W models too, and the maximum mains power consumption listed by the manufacturer for all four models *is the same*! This is suspicious. Hence: *Ask the manufacturer for help.*

Answer (score 1):

If a 100W cut takes 4x as long as 500W cut then a 100W cutter saves power but loses surgical time, but if it takes 5x as long then its the same amount of energy E=P*t.  Efficiency =Pout/Pin and is usually better for higher power equipment unless used at minimum levels. Talk to supplier for efficiency vs settings.

When not in use compare standby power when not cutting or measure it.

> I would go for the highest power model to save surgical time and use it sparingly and according to the surface area of the cut.

Although the cutter uses pulsed 380kHz or 480kHz at a rep rate of 33 kHz and possibly a much higher voltage to start ionization, I computed the rms voltage for each setting.

For a V source and rated load R [Ohms] and Power (Watts);
Vrms= √(P*R) from P=V²rms/R

Battery capacity = Ah*V = Wh rated for 20h load.
Reduce capacity if discharge time is less.

If R is open circuit, then Pd=0 except for internal idle power.
This can be tested with a DMM current meter.

```
          Pd   R    Vrms    Mode
```

PURE  ....  400W 500Ω  447V    MONOPOLAR CUT
BLEND 1 320W 300Ω  310V
BLEND 2 240W 300Ω  268V
BLEND 3 160W 300Ω  219V

FORCED  120W 500Ω  245V    MONOPOLAR COAG
SOFT  ...  120W 500Ω  245V
SPRAY .  100W 300Ω  173V

STD  ....   100W 100Ω  100V    BIPOLAR
SOFT ....    80W 100Ω ,  89V
CUT ....    100W 200Ω  141V

Of course these std load R values are dynamic and never constant.
tony.sunnysky@gmale   ;) EE since 1975